# Некорректная работа bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Подскажите, почему некоторые классы bootstrap отображают элементы не так как надо?

К примеру, вот простая страница: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23725639/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
  <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>yep</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>
  <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="button">Большая кнопка</button>
  <button class="btn btn-large" type="button">Большая кнопка</button>
</p>
<p>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Кнопка по умолчанию</button>
  <button class="btn" type="button">Кнопка по умолчанию</button>
</p>
<p>
  <button class="btn btn-small btn-primary" type="button">Маленькая кнопка</button>
  <button class="btn btn-small" type="button">Маленькая кнопка</button>
</p>
<p>
  <button class="btn btn-mini btn-primary" type="button">Мини-кнопка</button>
  <button class="btn btn-mini" type="button">Мини-кнопка</button>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Вот результат:

[image: выводимый результат]

А ожидается такая картина:

[image: требуемый результат]

Хотя с путями все в порядке, по-моему.

Comment: Вы какой bootstrap используете?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 1) Bootstrap 2.3.2

Вы взяли код от второго Бутстрапа, а подключили третий. Со стилями от версии 2.3.2 выглядит как надо:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<p>
  <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="button">Большая кнопка</button>
  <button class="btn btn-large" type="button">Большая кнопка</button>
</p>
<p>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Кнопка по умолчанию</button>
  <button class="btn" type="button">Кнопка по умолчанию</button>
</p>
<p>
  <button class="btn btn-small btn-primary" type="button">Маленькая кнопка</button>
  <button class="btn btn-small" type="button">Маленькая кнопка</button>
</p>
<p>
  <button class="btn btn-mini btn-primary" type="button">Мини-кнопка</button>
  <button class="btn btn-mini" type="button">Мини-кнопка</button>
</p>
```

### 2) Bootstrap 3.3.7

Чтобы заработало с третьим Бутстрапом, поменяйте три вещи:

1. Как советует [soledar10](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/610019/208926), задайте размер кнопок [классами `.btn-lg`, `.btn-sm` и `.btn-xs`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons-sizes).
2. Как советует [Byulent](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/610018/208926), подключите [тему по умолчанию](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/theme/), чтобы на кнопках появились объём и тени.
3. И добавьте серым кнопкам [класс `.btn-default`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons-options).

Получится:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<p>
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="button">Большая кнопка</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg" type="button">Большая кнопка</button>
</p>
<p>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Кнопка по умолчанию</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Кнопка по умолчанию</button>
</p>
<p>
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="button">Маленькая кнопка</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" type="button">Маленькая кнопка</button>
</p>
<p>
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" type="button">Мини-кнопка</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" type="button">Мини-кнопка</button>
</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте подключить `bootstrap-theme.css` (`bootstrap-theme.min.css`).

Да, и лучше использовать либо только полные файлы, либо только минифицированные.

Answer (score 2):

Необходимо использовать классы с приставкой `-lg`, `-sm`, `-xs`

Bootstrap [buttons-sizes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons-sizes)

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<p>
  <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="button">Большая кнопка</button>
  <button class="btn btn-lg" type="button">Большая кнопка</button>
</p>
<p>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Кнопка по умолчанию</button>
  <button class="btn" type="button">Кнопка по умолчанию</button>
</p>
<p>
  <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" type="button">Маленькая кнопка</button>
  <button class="btn btn-sm" type="button">Маленькая кнопка</button>
</p>
<p>
  <button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" type="button">Мини-кнопка</button>
  <button class="btn btn-xs" type="button">Мини-кнопка</button>
</p>
```